# Get THIS value from multiple input with same name IN INLINE-EDITING table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this situation. 
I've created a table with inline-editing (using jQ), and every row have its edit button. So if I want for instance, to edit first row, I click on edit button and it opens me his input field. Every opened row for editing has its save button which id is connected with id of that property in row. 
Now, **how can I get to that input value using php**? I have to mention every input is with same attribute-name -> they are all creating dynamically.

php

```
$new_tname = $_POST['edit_team']; ?????????????????????????????????

if (isset($_GET['save_tid'])) {
$tid = $_GET['save_tid'];
$team = Team::getById($tid);

if ($tid == $team->team_id) {


  $team->name = $new_tname;
  $team->save();
}
```

}

html/php

```
<?php 
                  $teams = Team::getAll();
                  foreach ($teams as $team) {
                    $tname = $team->name;
                    $tid = $team->team_id;


                    echo "<tr>
                    <td>
                    <a href='#' class='editable' style='margin-left: 2px;'>".$tname."</a><form method='POST' action=''><input type='text' class='editshow form-control col-sm-3' aria-label='Sizing example input' aria-describedby='inputGroup-sizing-sm' name='edit_teams' value='".$tname."'></form><a href='teams.php?save_tid={$tid}' style='margin-left: 2px; margin-top:3px;' class='btn btn-success btn-sm editshow'>Save</a>
                    </td>";

                    echo "<td>
                    <button  class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEdit'".$tid."'>Edit</button> | <a href='teams.php?delete_tid={$tid}' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>";
                  }

var_dump($new_tname) throws me a NOTICE: Undefined variable: edit_team
```

I'm assuming php can't find which edit_team(because they are multiple), isset($_POST['edit_team']) is not solution on this because it throws me NULL,

and here is jQ for inline-editing

jQ

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".editshow").hide();
  $(".btnEdit").click(function(){
    let btnEdit = $(this),
    containerEl = btnEdit.closest("tr");
    containerEl.find(".editshow").toggle();
  });
</script>
```

Is there any solution with php or? I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: So you are clicking on a link to “Save” (`<a href='teams.php?save_tid={$tid}' style='margin-left: 2px; margin-top:3px;' class='btn btn-success btn-sm editshow'>Save</a>`),  but expecting/wanting to pass the form value before it by `$_POST`?

Comment: of course i should take data first, and after that save it :D but still it's same.. notice undefined variable

Comment: You need some front and scripting here, so when the save link is clicked you can get the edited field and create a form body.

Comment: ok, but how? can u give me some example, or guide... I would be very thankful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is this: when you click on those links (the save or delete), you don't actually tell the server what it is you are updating. The link has no means of knowing, in and of itself, what fields it is sending, or whether they have been updated, or anything. You are doing something *dynamic* on the page, and in this case, that will mean scripting.

It is an order of magnitude more complex than what you have done with the toggle thing, so be warned -- you have just jumped in at the deep end. I have started building something that will show you how it **could** be done, but this is by no means complete, or accurate. We don't know what your php is really doing by the snapshot you have given us.

Here is a code block I've built, simply as a prototype. I'll describe it in deeper detail below:

```
$(function(){
  let updateTeamUrl = "SET_THIS_TO_THE_UPDATE_URL";

  // We'll also save these as references to all the action buttons.
  let actionItems = {
    editBtn: $(".btnEdit"),
    saveBtn: $(".save-btn"),
    deleteBtn: $(".btnDelete")
  }
  $(".editshow").hide();
  // Here we assign the actions to the various buttons/anchors
  actionItems.editBtn.on("click", toggleEdit);
  actionItems.saveBtn.on("click", saveTeam);
  actionItems.deleteBtn.on("click", confirmDelete)

  // Below are the actions we assign above, or support functions for them

  /**
   * toggleEdit() is triggered when the "Edit" button is clicked. This
   *   hides the team name text element, and displays the editable field.
   **/
  function toggleEdit(event){
    let teamContainer = $(this).closest("tr");
    teamContainer.find(".editshow").toggle();
    teamContainer.find(".editable").toggle();
  }

  /**
   * saveTeam() crawls up the DOM tree to the closest "tr" node, and gets
   *  the custom "data-teamid" attribute there. Using that, we can create
   *  a JSON object that we will send to the backend.
   **/
  function saveTeam(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let clickedEl = $(this),
        teamContainer = clickedEl.closest("tr"),
        teamNameEl = teamContainer.find(".editshow");
    let payloadToSend = {
      // We need a mechanism to identify what team we're updating
      teamId: teamContainer.data("teamid"),
      // This will eventually hold any and all updates.
      updates: {
        /* We'll create this empty, and fill it as we need.*/
      }
    };

    // I created a data attribute on the input, "data-original", and
    //  set it to the same value as the input. By comparing these, we
    //  can see if an input has, in fact, been updated.
    if(teamNameEl.data("original") !== teamNameEl.val() ){
      /**
       * The only thing we are updating in this pass is the team name.
       *  So we can update our "payload", then simply send the post request.
       **/
      payloadToSend.updates.name = teamNameEl.val();

      /**
       * When we POST, we need a URL and a string we'll send. 
       *  What we'll do is take the payload, and run it through
       *  JSON.stringify() to convert it to a string.
       *  Then, when we call $.post(), we can also add a .done() and
       *  .fail() handler. These will run when the save is complete,
       *  or when it fails.
       * 
       **/
      let postRequest = $.post(UpdateTeamUrl, JSON.stringify(payloadToSend) )
              .done(function(returnedData){
                console.log("Update succeeded: "+returnedData)
              })
              .fail(function(error){
                console.error("Update had an error: "+error)
              })
              .always(function(){
                teamContainer.find(".editshow").toggle();
                teamContainer.find("editable").toggle();
              });
    }
  } // end saveTeam();

  function confirmDelete(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let clickedEl = $(this),
        teamContainer = clickedEl.closest("tr"),
        teamId = teamContainer.data("teamid"),
        teamName = teamContainer.find("[name='edit_teams']").val();


    if(confirm("are you sure you want to delete the team "+teamId+": "+teamName+"?") ){
      console.log("Deleting!")
    } else {
      console.log("false alarm.")
    }
  }
})
```

Also, the HTML to support this needs to change a little: the `<tr>` gets a data attribute `data-teamid`, the `<input>` gets a data attribute `data-original`, and the form element that wrapped the input has been removed. Here's the HTML (without the PHP to construct it):

```
    <tr data-teamid="1">
      <td>
        <a href='#' class='editable' style='margin-left: 2px;'>Team Name</a>: <input type='text' class='editshow form-control col-sm-3' aria-label='Sizing example input' aria-describedby='inputGroup-sizing-sm' name='edit_teams' data-original='Team Name' value='Team Name'> <a href='teams.php?save_tid={$tid}' style='margin-left: 2px; margin-top:3px;' class='btn btn-success btn-sm editshow save-btn'>Save</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button  class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEdit team-1'>Edit</button> | <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnDelete'>Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

As I've said, this is getting pretty complex.

First, I moved all your "actions" into a javascript object. If I add other actions, I simply update them there. Then I attach listeners using `.on(...)` for each action I want to handle: edit, save and delete. For each of these, I wrote a function that will handle the action itself: `toggleEdit(...)` for the edit, `saveTeam(...)` for the save, and `confirmDelete` for the delete. Each action is self-contained, making editing a little easier.

The `toggleEdit(...)` is almost exactly what you had before. I don't think I changed much in that one, so it should look pretty familiar.

The `saveTeam(...)` is the one you're asking about now, and it is the complex bit. First, we climb back up the DOM tree to the `<tr>`, and use `.data("teamid")` to get the id of the team we're editing. Then we start creating a javascript Object, which I've called `payloadToSend`. In this, we have an attribute `teamId`, and a nested object `updates`. Next, we check to see if the text input has been updated (by comparing its value with that `data-original` attribute I added). If it hasn't changed, we don't need to update. If it **has**, then we update the `payloadToSend` by adding `name` to the `payloadToSend.updates` object, and we use `$.post(...)` to actually send the POST request. $.post() takes a URL and some data. We'll send the `payloadToSend` object as that data, which should show up in php as either `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`. In addition, the `$.post(...)` includes two conditional callbacks, `.done(...)` and `.fail(...)`, and one "absolute" callback, `.always(...)`

`.done(...)` runs when the server-side request has returned with a successful complete, and `.fail(...)` handles a back-end failure with an error message. In either case, though, we `.always(...)` want to hide the editable and show the team name again.

At this point, the `confirmDelete` action doesn't do anything more than get that same teamId, and pop up a basic confirmation dialog. The delete action is quite a bit more than that, and beyond the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some additional processing and filtering for the security of the data but a simple solution is to change the name of the field to **edit_teams_{$tid}** and in your php loop through the passed form fields:

```
    <?php
        foreach($_POST as $field_name => $field_value){
           if(substr($field_name,"edit_teams") !== false){
              $edit_teams = $field_value;
              $team_id = str_replace("edit_teams_","",$field_name);
           }
    }
?>
```