# set select in option php: Undefined property

Tags: php

Can someone explain me why I can't list items in select control? If I disable public $team_id in my Team class, and make new object `$selectedHome_id`, and after that correct this line of code to `$selectedHome_id == $team->team_id` I can list data, but I can't select the item.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcoXb.png)

matches.php

```
<?php include("config.php"); 
  $selectedTeam = new Team();

  if (isset($_GET['htid'])) {
  $selectedHome_id = Team::getById($_GET['htid']);
  } 
  ?>

<select class="custom-select-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" onchange="window.location='?htid='+this.value" name="selHomeTeam">
                    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
                    <?php 
                    $selectedHome_id = new Team();
                    $teams = Team::getAll();
                    foreach ($teams as $team) {
                      echo "<option " .($selectedHome_id->team_id== $team->team_id?"selected":""). " value='{$team->team_id}'>{$team->name}</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <option value="1">One</option>
                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                  </select>
```

Team.php

```
class Team extends ActiveRecord {
public $team_id; 
public $name;
public static $table = "teams";
public static $key = "team_id";
}
```

Comment: The `undefined property` warnings are probably causing your select html to be  invalid. Fix all of your php warnings.

Comment: `$selectedHome_id` is an instance of `Team`, but that class does not have a property named `id` ... it has one named `team_id`.

Comment: `$selectedHome_id->id` isn't `selectedHome_id->team_id`

Comment: yeah, i've already did that. instead id, I've changed team_id, but still the same..

Comment: This is the only place in the code you have shown, where `->id` occurs. So if you changed that, then at least the error message should change with it (and not still mention that same property name as before.)

Comment: That line is the line the error message refers to, yes?

Comment: @misorude yes, that is the line where is the error message...

Comment: @JuanCaicedo even when I change, it still gives me a error.. only this time undefined property $team_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you check to see if you have been passed a `$_GET['htid']` and, if you have, then you get that `Team`. Then, within your options, you promptly replace this with a new `Team` -- what do you think the `team_id` would be set to, with this new `Team`?

Perhaps, rather than

```
if (isset($_GET['htid'])) {
  $selectedHome_id = Team::getById($_GET['htid']);
}
```

you may want to

```
if (isset($_GET['htid'])) {
  $selectedHome_id = Team::getById($_GET['htid']);
} else {
  $selectedHome_id = new Team(); 
}
```

By doing this, when you get to the ternary comparison in your option, `$selectedHome_id` is set to something.

Without seeing the full code, though, we lack both intent and context.

Comment: Ok now I I get rid of the notice msg, but I can't keep selected any option if I click. When I click, in url I have clicked option id, but it keeps returning me on -1

Comment: Did you see my answer to your other question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280679/get-this-value-from-multiple-input-with-same-name-in-inline-editing-table

Comment: Yeah, I didn't implement it yet, but I've read it and it seems that will help me. So thank you, I forgot to accept your answer. But still on this I have a problem, if I put in url ...?htid=5 for example, it doesn't shows me an error, but when is empty, or just type in url matches.php there is a notice for undefined property. Ps: I'm still learning all of this.. and I'm new at site and u've helped me quite a lot :D so THANK YOU.

Comment: Glad to help. Do you have this on a public dev server somewhere, where I can see the error you're getting? Or have you pushed your codebase to git, somewhere I can clone and replicate it?

Comment: Have you tinkered with learning sites at all yet? I strongly recommend taking a look at something  like "The Odin Project" or FreeCodeCamp (http://www.freecodecamp.org/). It might give you a better handle on javascript, as well as consuming APIs.

Comment: I will take a look of this site, thank youu. I will push project to git now, and I will send u, I hope u will find out whats happening with my code

Comment: Click on my name to see my profile, my email is right in there. Hope to be able to help. ;)

Comment: I've mailed u, hope u will see it